# Creating view in SQL Server 2008 using SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, schema

I have create view using SSMS but I don't find option to change schema. How do I change schema in this case?

Comment: You want to change the view? Rightclick, Design (or edit)

Comment: @Matten Can't we choose that while creating it and I don't find it in design too

Comment: @Kitex... maybe just not enough coffee, but I don't understand your question :-) In SSMS, you can create a view graphically by modelling the required tables, columns and linking them to each other (instead of writing the necessary sql code). So what is you problem?

Comment: @Matten :) well the schema name is always dbo

Comment: @Kitex - Simplest soulution is not to bother with the view designer. It doesn't support constructs like `row_number`, and mangles your code formatting. With intellisense in the script environment now can think of no good reason for wanting to use it.

Comment: @Martin Felt easy to use GUI :) and though there might be feature

Comment: Totally agree with @Martin. There are several other bugs with the view designer. "Easy" is not the same as "better" - especially when it changes the intended logic of your query. Even worse if you don't catch it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the view to a new schema via TSQL `ALTER SCHEMA ... TRANSFER ...`. Full example below

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Foo
AS
SELECT 1 AS X

GO

CREATE SCHEMA bar

GO
ALTER SCHEMA bar TRANSFER dbo.Foo;

SELECT *
FROM bar.Foo
```

In general just create it in the correct schema with `CREATE VIEW bar.xyz`.

As far as the SSMS View designer goes the dialogue that comes up on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> just accepts a name and has nowhere to input a schema but before saving the view you can bring up the properties window (with <kbd>F4</kbd>) and define the schema there.

[image]